# Fiddler not showing websocket protocol using ws prefix

Tags: debugging, websocket, fiddler

I use fiddler to review many of the `http` and `https` communications from our application. We have a websocket implementation connected to a phoenix/elixir server using the `ws` prefix. So our url looks like `ws://{ip}:4000/socket/websocket`. None of the communications from our application to this end point are visible in Fiddler.

I can see all `http` and `https` traffic we're doing, but not the websocket calls. The websocket connections are working and the app is sending and receiving messages correctly, but I'd like to be able to see the messages to monitor this part of the application.

Any idea how to make the `ws` prefix visible in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Script Language C#

```
public static void OnWebSocketMessage(WebSocketMessage oMsg) {
    // Log Message to the LOG tab
    FiddlerObject.log(oMsg.ToString());
}
```

JScript.Net

```
static function OnWebSocketMessage(oMsg: WebSocketMessage) {
    // Log Message to the LOG tab
    FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString(oMsg.ToString());
}
```

add above code to FiddlerScript, you will see log on the fiddler log tab.

([Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler))